# Elementary OS 0.3.2 Freya 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 downloading VLC

Tags: release-freya, command-line, vlc

I've been trying to download the latest version of VLC which is 3.something (my elementary OS has vlc 2.1.6 rincewind).

If I go to the Videolan download page or if I use Software Center they both revert to the old version of VLC which is no longer supported.

***Do I have to use Terminal?***

In which case is anybody able to tell me the exact commands to use as I have no idea whatsoever how to use the command line.

Any help gratefully appreciated. When adding tags, the information said that Freya has been superseded by Loki.

- Should I simply upgrade to Loki?
- Is Loki a better OS and does it update VLC, which Freya doesn't?
- Also, as a supplementary, does anyone know of a good idiot's guide to using the command line?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you have the latest version of VLC the commands you would use  are

```
$ sudo apt-get update 

$ sudo apt-get upgrade 

$ sudo apt-get install vlc
```

this will install the latest VLC that is in your repo's

Answer (score 0):

This is still an old question but that's why there was a different version between the **AppCenter** and the official repository.

It is possible to install an application, without touching the `Source.list` via the well-known command:

```
$ sudo apt install <package-name>
```

But elementary OS is based on Ubuntu and therefore also follows the packages for the Ubuntu distribution on which it is based. If a version of Ubuntu does not support or validate a version of a package, then you will not have the latest version of the package via the classic method above

You can install a package in this most recent version generally by following the tutorial from the official website

At the time of this writing, in **December 2019**, VideoLAN recommends using `Snap` to install the latest stable package for Ubuntu OS

Informations [here](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html)

So if today (2019) we want the very latest version of VLC through the official repository, we must do these commands

```
# Install snap
# add the arg -y for auto answer Yes (confirm action)
$ sudo apt install snap -y

# Install VLC via snap
$ sudo snap install vlc
```